# How to add the tick labels after set the boundary?

Tags: cartopy

I tried to add tick labels after using .set_boundary(), but failed.How to achieve it？

```
ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -60], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ax1.gridlines()

ax2.gridlines()
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)
ax2.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax2.transAxes)

ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks for your post. When you ask questions on stackoverflow you need do 2 things which you have not done. Firstly you need to give your question more context, what language are you coding in, what library are you using, versions etc. The more context you give the more people can help you. Secondly you need to add tags to your question too, the tags help categorise your post so that the users with the correct knowledge can find your question and help. Adjust your question and I am sure someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I use path's vertices and path's code explicitely to create `matplotlib.path` that is used for the circular boundary of the second map. By doing so, the gridlines' labels are not disturbed and rendered as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.path as mpath

use_proj = ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()
extent = [-180, 180, -90, -50]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 4.5))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, projection=use_proj)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, projection=use_proj)

ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -60], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ax1.gridlines()
# draw graticule (meridian and parallel lines)
gls1 = ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), lw=1, color="gray",
        y_inline=True, xlocs=range(-180,180,30), ylocs=range(-90,-40,10))

# Value for r_extent is obtained by trial and error
# get it with `ax2.get_ylim()` after running this code
r_extent = 3331997.462
r_extent *= 1.01       #increase a bit for better result
ax2.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -59], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.gridlines()
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
# draw graticule (meridian and parallel lines)
gls2 = ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), lw=1, color="gray",
        y_inline=True, xlocs=range(-180,180,30), ylocs=range(-90,-40,10))
#ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True, ylocs=[-80,-70,-60])

# set the plot limits
ax2.set_xlim(-r_extent, r_extent)
ax2.set_ylim(-r_extent, r_extent)

# Prep circular boundary
circle_path = mpath.Path.unit_circle()
circle_path = mpath.Path(circle_path.vertices.copy() * r_extent,
                           circle_path.codes.copy())

#set circular boundary
#this method will not interfere with the gridlines' labels 
ax2.set_boundary(circle_path)
ax2.set_frame_on(False)  #hide the boundary frame

plt.show()
```

[image: sstereo]

Answer (score 0):

There is missing code in your example so I can't be sure it will solve your problem, but Cartopy allows longitude and latitude labeling to all projections starting only with version 0.18 ([whats new](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/whats_new.html) and [PR](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/1117)). Before that only PlateCarree and Mercator were allowed and any other projection would fail with error:

`TypeError: Cannot label gridlines on a SouthPolarStereo plot. Only PlateCarree and Mercator plots are currently supported.`

With v0.18 the code (that I got from the PR linked above) makes the lonlat labels just fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

projection = ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()
extent = [-180, 180, -90, -60]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=projection)
ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', color='k')
ax.gridlines(color='lightgrey', linestyle='-', draw_labels=True)
```

[image: Polar plot with labels]